# Stack trace not visible on Eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, stack-trace, classnotfoundexception, android-logcat

Hello everybody I am new of Eclipse and Java. I want to see the stack trace of a ClassNotFoundException but I cannot see it on LogCat.
I tried all the possible output here in the code that I cannot see absolutely nothing in the logcat.

```
try{
    Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
    }
catch(ClassNotFoundException e){
    e.printStackTrace();
    Log.d("appcani","I am here");
    Log.d("YOUR_APP_LOG_TAG", "I got an error", e);
    }
```

It seems it doesn't go inside the catch but without the catch it gives the ClassNotFoundException so it should go inside the catch.

I already tried to use:

```
catch(Exception e)
```

but it doesn't work as well

Comment: ok my comment is off-topic but: for His(Flying Spaghetti Monster) glory, your sanity and to save little kittens, please, do not use jdbc directly on android platform

Comment: Thank you. Maybe we can discuss this on private, but I have still to study design patterns!

Comment: You could just try `catch(Exception e)` and see if it works.

Comment: I tried:it doesn't work